# Fetch Image from server by using url with Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, image, caching, universal-image-loader

I am successfully fetching and caching image from server url by **using Universal Image Loader**. My `DisplayImageOptions` are given below.

```
new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.home_back_img)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.home_back_img)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.home_back_img)
                .build();
```

My problem is, when I updates image in server(with same file name), the image is not updated in application, its just using the cached file itself. Is there is any solution for this? Yes we can avoid caching, but then it might take some time to load the image every time, rather than avoid caching it would be nice if any solution exists. Help will be appreciated!

Comment: Try this link alex.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/19386142/2219600

Comment: @amalBit As the description in the above link, it is equal to avoid caching. Right?

Answer (score 1):

You must use different name to get the updated photo. Because , the image already stored in your local cache by the same name. So, It will never call to network to download the image .

Or , Clear your application cache , then you will get the updated image.

Comment: is UIL saves image by using name or any other id?

Comment: the name is mainly the full length URL . So, every time you keep the same url and the image name (url+image Like : www.abc.com/def.com) it check that the photo with the full length name is already stored , so , it don't make any other request . That's why you don't get the updated photo.

Comment: @Alex Chengalan,  if you get your answer please accept my answer.

Comment: Actually, this didnt helped me friend. I end up with avoid caching for now :(