# Universal Image loader not refresh image if changed from server with same URL

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

- I have used Universal Image Loader for load image from a server and also getting cached it into memory for fast loading.
- But from server side used the same URL for update image.
- For eg., www.example.com/xyz.png is URL for the image when they needed to update image they return same URL with a different image.
- In this case, Universal Image Loader return image which is previously cached in memory (I think it cached image using its related URL).
- So, I needed to Change image if URL returned a different image.

This is my code which I use for load image

## DisplayImageOption.java

```
public class DisplayImageOption {

public static DisplayImageOptions getDisplayImage() {
    // .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(0))
    return new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnLoading(R.mipmap.icon_place_holder)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.mipmap.icon_place_holder)
            .showImageOnFail(R.mipmap.icon_place_holder)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .considerExifParams(true).build();
}

public static DisplayImageOptions getDisplayRoundedImage() {
    return new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnLoading(R.mipmap.icon_place_holder)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.mipmap.icon_place_holder)
            .showImageOnFail(R.mipmap.icon_place_holder)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(100)).build();
    }
}
```

## Code for Image Loading

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, imageView, DisplayImageOption.getDisplayImage());
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ImageLoaderConfiguration` add `diskCache` option.

```
File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getCacheDirectory(context);
long cacheAge = 10L;

ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
        .diskCache(new LimitedAgeDiscCache(cacheDir, cacheAge)) // this will make the cache to remain for 10 seconds only
        .build();
```

Then set it on `ImageLoader` and display image with your `DisplayImageOption`

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, imageView, DisplayImageOption.getDisplayImage());
```

**What it does?**
Taken from [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Useful-Info)

> **LimitedAgeDiscCache** (Size-unlimited cache with limited files' lifetime. If age of cached file exceeds defined limit then it will be deleted from cache.)

And this piece of code is from Android-Universal-Image-Loader's [`LimitedAgeDiskCache.java`](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/nostra13/universalimageloader/cache/disc/impl/LimitedAgeDiskCache.java) class.

```
/**
     * @param cacheDir Directory for file caching
     * @param maxAge   Max file age (in seconds). If file age will exceed this value then it'll be removed on next
     *                 treatment (and therefore be reloaded).
     */
    public LimitedAgeDiskCache(File cacheDir, long maxAge) {
        this(cacheDir, null, DefaultConfigurationFactory.createFileNameGenerator(), maxAge);
}
```

You may like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054192/universal-image-loader-can-i-use-cache-but-also-refresh-it) approach as well.

Comment: Thanks for answer.I also getting this type of answers but this code clear my all image cache, i needed like UIL check image URL with its data in cache if data are same then image load from cache and if data are different then previous cache associated with image URL gets clear and then create new cache.

Comment: Yeah, take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054192/universal-image-loader-can-i-use-cache-but-also-refresh-it